# What temperature should a beam of light be at to burn through a person in a couple of seconds?

Tags: science-fiction, physics, weapons, super-powers, light

A magical technician who creates weapons with lenses, LEDs, and mirrors.

What temperature should a beam of light be at to burn through a person in a couple of seconds? Cut a bone in a couple of seconds? A beam, not a laser. The beam may be 1 millimeter thick.

Comment: It's not temperature so much as energy-density. Temperature, when applied to color, simply specifies the wavelength but says nothing about how much of it there is. As for the how-much question, that I don't know how to calculate an answer for.

Comment: This looks like a physics question rather than a question about building a fictional world.

Comment: Light does not have a temperature. The question makes no sense.

Comment: As a general note: It's certainly possible to [assign a temperature to an ensemble of photons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59456/56299), but it's really just a proxy for their average energy - and energy and intensity are the quantities you're interested in.

Comment: Are you assuming a person bound and unable to move, like James Bond in Goldfinger? Otherwise if zapping someone, they WILL move, spreading the effect over a considerable area (unless the beam is so strong as to be almost instantaneous).

Comment: @HDE 226868: But for an application like this, we don't really care about the energy of the photons.  (That is, a blue photon having more energy than a red one).  We care about the energy carried by a lot of photons. Consider solar furnaces like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odeillo_solar_furnace  It's just concentrating ordinary sunlight, collected from a large area, onto a small one.  No different from starting fires with a magnifying glass, which you probably did as a kid.  So the question really isn't answerable in its present form.

Comment: @jamesqf Hence why I mentioned the intensity of the beam.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is scientifically inaccurate.

Answer (score 8):

> A beam, not a laser.

Irrelevant in this case.

> What temperature should a beam of light be at to burn through a person in a couple of seconds? Cut a bone in a couple of seconds?

It's not about temperature, it's about power output.

Lasers are used in medicine to cut flesh. Decade and a half ago I had wisdom teeth that did not surface, my dentist cut through my gum with lasers. My kid was tongue tied, his dentist slashed his tongue with lasers.

The whole cutting took a few seconds each time, but we're talking a few millimeters of flesh only here. Bone could take longer. So clearly medical lasers won't do.

Next step up in power is using industrial lasers. The first machine in [this page](https://www.tianchengroup.com/Product-Category.html) can cut steel sheets at a rate of 140 meters per minute, and has a wattage around up to 4 kW. I think this would do for your flesh and bone piercing needs.

Comment: Nitpick:  That machine can pass material through it at 140 m/s, it doesn't say it can cut steel sheets at that speed.  And you missed it's bigger cousin at 200 m/s and 20,000W.

Comment: @LorenPechtel #1, that's 140m/min, not second. #2, the video shows a cutting speed of about 8mm per second, for reasonably thick plate (maybe 14mm). That's barely half a meter per minute. OTOH, a big chunk of the speed limitation for laser cutting is not how fast you can heat the target, but how fast you can get the gunk out of the cut. And steel is *easier* to lasercut than flesh. Much easier.

Comment: Fleshbags are wet, vaporizing leads to nasty steam which could obstruct the beam.

Comment: If it's not important whether it's a laser or not, why are lasers used IRL?  Just because that's the easiest thing to focus?

Comment: @A.B. practicality actually, but there are other means to burn stuff with light. Solar ovens come to mind, as well as [burning glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burning_glass).

Comment: @A. B.: It's not really a matter of focus, but that with lasers you can generate an intense beam directly.